# Installing QT 5.5 On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with error : QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method

Tags: software-installation, qt5

I've Downloaded **qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.0-2.run** file and tryed to install it using terminal, so I added execute permission and run it:

```
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.0-2.run
```

But it shows:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

and nothing happens.

What is the problem and how I can install it?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @Sadegh : I have also got the same issue when installing the qt5. This is due to the dependency of qt in sslv2 . We need to configure the packages by editing the source code of openssl. Proper steps are given by Tung Tran [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711863/installing-qt-5-5-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-throws-qt-network-ssl-error-on-terminal) . Thanks to [Tung Tran](https://askubuntu.com/users/477744/tung-tran)